# Best way to manage redis data

Tags: redis

Just getting started with redis, and I'm having a hard time managing the redis data.
Are there any tools that help give a visualization of my applications redis data?

Comment: Cant you use the CLI? How do you want to visualize it?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Keylord](http://protonail.com/products/keylord) - cross-platform GUI application for manage key-value databases like Redis, LevelDB, etc.

[image: Keylord application for manage Redis database]

- support Redis and LevelDB key-value databases
- SSH tunnels for Redis connections
- display keys in flat and hierarchical views
- can load millions of keys in background (use SCAN* command)
- can create/read/update/delete keys of different types
- clear and predictable UI

Answer (score 2):

There is [Redis Admin UI](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=381) / [on github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.RedisWebServices), it is .NET based.

I have not tried it myself, but the screenshots and the live demo look promising.

There is also [phpRedisAdmin](https://github.com/ErikDubbelboer/phpRedisAdmin) from ErikDubbelboer, which is working according to the poster of this very similar question: [phpMyAdmin equivalent to MySQL for Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394731/phpmyadmin-equivalent-to-mysql-for-redis)

At my company, when developing in Redis and dealing with a large number of keys, we create and maintain a custom management page while developing. The reason for this is that it allows us to create the best 'custom' representation of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think [AnotherRedisDesktopManager](https://github.com/qishibo/AnotherRedisDesktopManager) is a useful tool for managing redis, faster, better and more stable. What's more, it won't crash when loading a large number of keys.

[image: another-redis-desktop-manager-status]

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a tool like that (phpMyRedis), but there are no current working tools like that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

You can try FastoRedis [site programm](http://fastoredis.com) - crossplatform Redis GUI client based on `redis-cli`.

[image: Common screenshot]