# phpMyAdmin equivalent to MySQL for Redis?

Tags: php, redis

I use Predis to operate Redis. It will be a lot helpful if i have a tool like PhpMyAdmin, Which is very useful when developing apps backed on MySQL.

What is the phpMyAdmin equivalent to MySQL for Redis?

Answer (score 9):

I'm using redis-cli, but i'm sure you want something more.

You could try :

1. https://github.com/tnm/redweb
2. http://code.google.com/p/redis-admin/

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have check both out. redweb runs successfully, and redis-admin failed for the driver it uses is not update-to-date. I also use redis-cli now, cli is more flexible.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to accept this answer. Since you're new you should read the faq :http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: You linked to a fork of redweb, I think this is the most recently active version: https://github.com/tnm/redweb

Answer (score 6):

from [Redis web site](http://redis.io/clients) 
there three web Interface for Redis:

- [redom](https://github.com/steelThread/redmon)
- [phpRedisAdmin](https://github.com/ErikDubbelboer/phpRedisAdmin)
- [phpredmin](https://github.com/sasanrose/phpredmin)

Answer (score 4):

I recently wrote a new web panel for redis in php. You can find it under [redis.io/clients](http://redis.io/clients) and also on it's github page: https://github.com/sasanrose/phpredmin